# why cant I add list values [JAVA]

Tags: java

```
public class Basic {

    public static void main(String args[])   {



    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Setter {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(45);
    list.add(43);


}
```

it throws the following error:

Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
     QualifiedName
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete

how do i solve it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import in the middle of your source code.  Move those to the top of the file.  You also cannot put code like

```
list.add..
```

directly in the class.  It must be put in a static clause at least:

```
{
list.add(45);
list.add(43);
}
```

But I believe your issue is more of understanding how java works to begin with.  Do a few more tutorials, you're just putting everything in the wrong place.